# List of property names of a dictionary

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to extract the property names from a dictionary. Specifically, I have computed a PCA analysis over the bands of an image and now I would like to get the included PC1 values.

In order to do that, I computed a histogram of such values, but I am not able to extract the actual names of the properties from the dictionary (I am not interested into the histogram values).

```
var freqHist = ee.Dictionary( // Calculate frequency histogram
      pca_image.reduceRegion(
        {reducer:ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(), geometry:geometry, scale:1000, maxPixels:1e13})
        .get('pc1')
    )
print(freqHist)
```

Ideally I would be able to extract the values marked in red as e.g. a list.[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`freqHist.keys()`

> [ee.Dictionary.keys](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-dictionary-keys)
>
> Retrieve the keys of a dictionary as a list.
> The keys will be sorted in natural order.